# split violinplot with different ranges

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

I am trying to plot two variables with different ranges using split violinplots in seaborn.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('dummy_metric1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('dummy_metric2.csv')

fig, ax2 = plt.subplots()

sns.set_style('white')
palette1 = 'Set2'
palette2 = 'Set1'
colors_list = ['#78C850', '#F08030',  '#6890F0',  '#A8B820',  '#F8D030', '#E0C068', '#C03028', '#F85888', '#98D8D8']

ax1 = sns.violinplot(y=df1.Value,x=df1.modality,hue=df1.metric, palette=palette1, inner="stick")
xlim = ax1.get_xlim()
ylim = ax1.get_ylim()
for violin in ax1.collections:
    bbox = violin.get_paths()[0].get_extents()
    x0, y0, width, height = bbox.bounds
    violin.set_clip_path(plt.Rectangle((x0, y0), width / 2, height, transform=ax1.transData))
ax1.set_xlim(xlim)
ax1.set_ylim(ylim)
ax1.set_title("dummy")
ax1.set_ylabel("metric1")
ax1.set_xlabel("Modality")
ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')
ax1.legend_.remove()

ax2 = ax1.twinx() 

ax2 = sns.violinplot(y=df2.Value,x=df2.modality,hue=df2.metric, palette=palette2, inner=None)
xlim = ax2.get_xlim()
ylim = ax2.get_ylim()
for violin in ax2.collections:
    bbox = violin.get_paths()[0].get_extents()
    x0, y0, width, height = bbox.bounds
    violin.set_clip_path(plt.Rectangle((x0, y0), width / 2, height, transform=ax2.transData))
ax2.set_xlim(xlim)
ax2.set_ylim(ylim)
ax2.set_ylabel("Metric2")
ax2.set_xticklabels(ax2.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')
ax2.legend_.remove()

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

However, I am unable to use the right portion of the ax2 violins. Here's is the output.

[image]

When I do `violin.set_clip_path(plt.Rectangle((width/2, y0), width / 2, height, transform=ax2.transData))` I get this result:

[image]

Can someone explain what am I missing? Also, how can I manage having `inner="stick"`?

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach using `split=True` and dummy data to force a split with empty halves. For the left half, `metric` is set to `1` for the real data, and to `2` for the dummy data. And vice versa for the right half. We need to make sure all dataframes use the same categorical order for the `modality` column, to avoid a mix-up.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sns.set_style('white')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'modality': pd.Categorical.from_codes(np.random.randint(0, 3, 30), ['a', 'b', 'c']),
                    'Value': np.random.rand(30) * 25 + 50})
df1['metric'] = 1
df1_dummy = pd.DataFrame({'modality': pd.Categorical.from_codes([0], ['a', 'b', 'c']), 'Value': [np.nan]})
df1_dummy['metric'] = 2

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'modality': pd.Categorical.from_codes(np.random.randint(0, 3, 100), ['a', 'b', 'c']),
                    'Value': np.random.randn(100).cumsum() / 10 + 1})
df2['metric'] = 2
df2_dummy = pd.DataFrame({'modality': pd.Categorical.from_codes([0], ['a', 'b', 'c']), 'Value': [np.nan]})
df2_dummy['metric'] = 1

ax1 = sns.violinplot(y='Value', x='modality', hue='metric', palette=['turquoise', 'red'],
                     inner="stick", split=True, data=pd.concat([df1, df1_dummy]))
ax1.legend_.remove()
ax1.set_ylabel('metric 1')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.violinplot(y='Value', x='modality', hue='metric', palette=['turquoise', 'red'],
               inner="stick", split=True, data=pd.concat([df2, df2_dummy]), ax=ax2)
ax2.set_ylabel('metric 2')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.violinplot splitting with different value ranges]

PS: Here is a possible adaption of the original code:

- using `plt.Rectangle((x0+width/2, y0), width/2, height)` to clip the violins on ax2
- using the `ax=` parameter of `sns.violinplot()` to indicate the correct subplot
- not changing the xlim and ylim of neither ax
- making sure both dataframes use the same categorical order for `modality`
- to clip the "inner" lines, for `ax1`: loop through the lines, get their `x0` and `x1`, and shorten the line to `x0` and `(x0+x1)/2`
- similar for `ax2`: loop through the lines, get their `x0` and `x1`, and shorten the line to `(x0+x1)/2` and `x1`
- update the legend for `ax2` combining it with the legend of `ax1`, and then remove `ax1`'s legend

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'modality': pd.Categorical.from_codes(np.random.randint(0, 3, 30), ['a', 'b', 'c']),
                    'Value': np.random.rand(30) * 25 + 50})
df1['metric'] = 1
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'modality': pd.Categorical.from_codes(np.random.randint(0, 3, 100), ['a', 'b', 'c']),
                    'Value': np.random.randn(100).cumsum() / 10 + 1})
df2['metric'] = 2

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

sns.set_style('white')
palette1 = 'Set2'
palette2 = 'Set1'

sns.violinplot(y=df1.Value, x=df1.modality, hue=df1.metric, palette=palette1, inner="stick", ax=ax1)
for violin in ax1.collections:
    bbox = violin.get_paths()[0].get_extents()
    x0, y0, width, height = bbox.bounds
    violin.set_clip_path(plt.Rectangle((x0, y0), width / 2, height, transform=ax1.transData))
for line in ax1.lines:
    x = line.get_xdata()
    line.set_xdata([x[0], np.mean(x)])

ax1.set_ylabel("metric1")
ax1.set_xlabel("Modality")

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.violinplot(y=df2.Value, x=df2.modality, hue=df2.metric, palette=palette2, inner="stick", ax=ax2)
ylim = ax2.get_ylim()
for violin in ax2.collections:
    bbox = violin.get_paths()[0].get_extents()
    x0, y0, width, height = bbox.bounds
    violin.set_clip_path(plt.Rectangle((x0 + width / 2, y0), width / 2, height, transform=ax2.transData))
for line in ax2.lines:
    x = line.get_xdata()
    line.set_xdata([np.mean(x), x[1]])
ax2.set_ylabel("Metric2")
ax2.set_xticklabels(ax2.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')
ax2.legend(handles=ax1.legend_.legendHandles + ax2.legend_.legendHandles, title='Metric')
ax1.legend_.remove()

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Neat! Works for me. However, I would appreciate some insights on where I was going wrong with my approach. Has to be something minor...

Comment: It's hard to tell without reproducible data.  Certainly, you need to clip the other half for the ax2 violins, so `violin.set_clip_path(plt.Rectangle((x0+width/2, y0), width/2, height, transform=ax2.transData)`.  You'll also need to find a way to apply the same clipping to the "inner" lines.  I also think you should do `ax2.set_xlim(xlim)` with the x-limits of the `ax1`, and make sure the 'modality' column always has  the same categorical order.